# Changing the opacity of lines on a plot based on their value

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

Suppose I have the following Association,

```
f=<|"a:b" -> (2.888888888888889` x + 158.5679012345679` x^2 + 
      972.4261545496113` x^3 + 2782.574803223688` x^4 + 
      4689.153835062141` x^5 + 6158.852000788219` x^6 + 
      6193.345446598874` x^7 + 4759.487380195244` x^8 + 
      2828.1047688854555` x^9 + 1262.2623444432436` x^10 + 
      396.8075199523231` x^11 + 87.10349331793769` x^12 + 
      15.918345899682585` x^13 + 2.358273466619642` x^14)/(2 x + 
      142 x^2 + 994 x^3 + 3068 x^4 + 5440 x^5 + 7516 x^6 + 8061 x^7 + 
      6591 x^8 + 4215 x^9 + 2029 x^10 + 694 x^11 + 181 x^12 + 
      33 x^13 + 4 x^14), 
  "a:c" -> (1.9259259259259258` x + 154.85871056241427` x^2 + 
      1000.1077071584616` x^3 + 2910.6970670309593` x^4 + 
      4824.123299147454` x^5 + 6433.145771926378` x^6 + 
      6287.788973741406` x^7 + 4729.911569226189` x^8 + 
      2616.6377204567093` x^9 + 1072.3401991902406` x^10 + 
      300.41168315858073` x^11 + 66.12235989098919` x^12 + 
      9.795905169035438` x^13 + 1.179136733309821` x^14)/(2 x + 
      142 x^2 + 994 x^3 + 3068 x^4 + 5440 x^5 + 7516 x^6 + 8061 x^7 + 
      6591 x^8 + 4215 x^9 + 2029 x^10 + 694 x^11 + 181 x^12 + 
      33 x^13 + 4 x^14), 
  "a:d" -> (4.814814814814815` x + 154.85871056241427` x^2 + 
      992.0711273687954` x^3 + 2876.30182842498` x^4 + 
      4856.41660650529` x^5 + 6212.275496911057` x^6 + 
      6143.436265588593` x^7 + 4685.547852772606` x^8 + 
      2780.4000811927754` x^9 + 1173.8148471954553` x^10 + 
      376.33991077009017` x^11 + 87.73928523996643` x^12 + 
      12.244881461294296` x^13 + 1.7687050999647316` x^14)/(2 x + 
      142 x^2 + 994 x^3 + 3068 x^4 + 5440 x^5 + 7516 x^6 + 8061 x^7 + 
      6591 x^8 + 4215 x^9 + 2029 x^10 + 694 x^11 + 181 x^12 + 
      33 x^13 + 4 x^14), 
  "a:e" -> (1.9259259259259258` x + 154.85871056241427` x^2 + 
      1177.8054158410812` x^3 + 3305.3824300345664` x^4 + 
      5174.381478951672` x^5 + 6568.697926267911` x^6 + 
      6234.040624961103` x^7 + 4385.353371436694` x^8 + 
      2365.2980972400514` x^9 + 900.9303208030539` x^10 + 
      255.51499204916647` x^11 + 41.96226685389699` x^12 + 
      6.122440730647148` x^13 + 1.179136733309821` x^14)/(2 x + 
      142 x^2 + 994 x^3 + 3068 x^4 + 5440 x^5 + 7516 x^6 + 8061 x^7 + 
      6591 x^8 + 4215 x^9 + 2029 x^10 + 694 x^11 + 181 x^12 + 
      33 x^13 + 4 x^14), 
  "a:f" -> (2.888888888888889` x + 143.73113854595337` x^2 + 
      946.5305085606869` x^3 + 2706.9052782905346` x^4 + 
      4601.382281730587` x^5 + 6048.018180473671` x^6 + 
      6250.932963149198` x^7 + 4803.8510966488275` x^8 + 
      2905.7138876690697` x^9 + 1305.4576337968147` x^10 + 
      423.87758370946995` x^11 + 103.63408329068498` x^12 + 
      18.97956626500616` x^13 + 1.7687050999647316` x^14)/(2 x + 
      142 x^2 + 994 x^3 + 3068 x^4 + 5440 x^5 + 7516 x^6 + 8061 x^7 + 
      6591 x^8 + 4215 x^9 + 2029 x^10 + 694 x^11 + 181 x^12 + 
      33 x^13 + 4 x^14)|>;
```

I want to plot this for `x` between `2/26` and `1` can plot this as follow:

```
Plot[f // Values, {x, 2/26, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

For which I get:

[image]

Now question is how to sorts the opacity of the lines in the plot based on their `y` value? so that the line with highest value of `y` has the higher opacity and the line with lowest value of `y` has the lowest opacity, bear in mind that in reality my `f` has more number of polynomials and thus the opacity range should be such that it would work for any number of lines.

Update: 
To plot the curve with corresponding transparency we can use C. E.'s code as follow:

```
funcs = f // Values;
g = f // Keys;
getOpacities[values_] := 
 Range[Length[values]] /. 
  MapThread[Rule, {Ordering[values], Rest@Subdivide[Length[values]]}]

values = Table[funcs, {x, 2/26, 1, 0.01}];
opacities = Transpose[getOpacities /@ values];
interp = ListInterpolation[#, {{0, 1}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ 
   opacities;

colorf[opacityf_, x_] := 
 RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798, opacityf[x]]

Show@MapThread[
  Function[{f, opacityf}, 
   Plot[f, {x, 2/26, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLabels -> Placed[g, Before], Axes -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> (colorf[opacityf, #] &)]], {funcs, interp}]
```

where I made `g` as key list and used it later to label the curves according to their associations. However it seems the labels are getting messed up? Is there a fix for this?

Secondly I know to plot with different curve colours one can use

```
Plot[Evaluate[f // Values], {x, 2/26, 1}, 
 PlotLabels -> Placed[f // Keys, Before], Axes -> False]
```

I wonder if we can put this into C. E.'s code so essentially to have colours too and each curve would have different opacity with respect to its y value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paint over parts with white `RankedMax` functions with varying opacities:

```
funclist = Function /@ BesselJ[Range @ 4, #];
whiteouts = Function[x, #] & /@ (Style[RankedMax[Through[funclist @ x], #], 
   Opacity[Sqrt @ (( # - 1)/(1 + Length@funclist)), White]] & /@ Range[Length @ funclist]);

Plot[Evaluate[Join[Through[funclist @ x], Through[whiteouts @ x]]], {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[5], 
 PlotLabels -> Placed[TraditionalForm /@ Through[funclist@x], Above]]
```

[image]

```
funclist = Function[x, #] & /@ Values[f];
whiteouts = Function[x, #] & /@ (Style[RankedMax[Through[funclist @ x], #], 
  Opacity[Sqrt @ (( # - 1)/(1 + Length@funclist)), White]] & /@ Range[Length @ funclist]);

Plot[Evaluate[Join[Through[funclist @ x], Through[whiteouts @ x]]], {x, 0, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3], PlotRange -> {{0, .5}, {0.8, 1.3}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Clever! I like this very much!

Comment: Thank you @C.E.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ColorFunction` and the four-argument form of `RGBColor` to specify the opacity given `x`. All that's left, then, is to figure out what opacity to give for each function at each `x`. This can be done numerically.

```
funcs = {Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]};

getOpacities[values_] := Range[Length[values]] /. MapThread[Rule, {
    Ordering[values],
    Rest@Subdivide[Length[values]]
    }]

values = Table[funcs, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}];
opacities = Transpose[getOpacities /@ values];
interp = ListInterpolation[#, {{0, 1}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ opacities;

colorf[opacityf_, x_] := RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798, opacityf[x]]

Show@MapThread[Function[{f, opacityf},
   Plot[f, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> (colorf[opacityf, #] &)]
   ], {funcs, interp}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the code changes as described in the comments & corresponding plot for your functions, after setting `PlotRange` and the starting `x` appropriately:

```
funcs = fValues;

getOpacities[values_] := 
 Range[Length[values]] /. 
  MapThread[Rule, {Ordering[values], Rest@Subdivide[Length[values]]}]

values = Table[funcs, {x, 2/26, 1, 0.01}];
opacities = Transpose[getOpacities /@ values];
interp = ListInterpolation[#, {{2/26, 1}}, 
     InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ opacities;

colorf[opacityf_, x_] := 
 RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798, opacityf[x]]

Show@MapThread[
  Function[{f, opacityf},
   Plot[f, {x, 2/26, 1},
    ColorFunction -> (colorf[opacityf, #] &),
    PlotRange -> All]
   ], {funcs, interp}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, so to run the code I made `funcs=f // Values` and commented out the `values` but don't get the plot as yours. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @William You have to specify `PlotRange -> All` and you also have to change `2 Pi` to `1` in two places. You also have to change `0` to `2/26` in the same two places.

Comment: Thanks this works can you see the update on this question, I am trying to change your code a little to include labels and colours. Any help on that is appreciated.

Comment: @William Thread over `{funcs, interp, colors}` instead of `{funcs, interp}`, where `colors` is your desired list of colors. Then pass the color `colorf` and make the suitable adjustment in `RGBColor`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this works too...

```
fPlot[f_] := Module[{fValues, fValuesSorted},
  fValues = Values[f];
  fValuesSorted = Sort[fValues];
  
  Plot[fValuesSorted, {x, 2/26, 1},
   PlotRange -> All,
   PlotStyle -> (Lighter[Black, #] & /@ 
      Table[1 - 1/i, {i, Length[fValues]}])]
  ]

fPlot[f]
```

Version 2 addressing @Williams comment...

```
fPlot2[f_] := Module[{fValues, fValuesSorted},
  fValues = Values[f];
  fValuesSorted = 
   Sort[fValues, FindMaximum[#, {x, 2/26, 1}] & /@ fValues];
  
  Plot[fValuesSorted, {x, 2/26, 1},
   PlotRange -> All,
   PlotStyle -> (Lighter[Black, #] & /@ 
      Table[1 - 1/i, {i, Length[fValues]}])]
  ]

fPlot2[f]
```

Version 1

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Version 2

[image: Version 2]

Hmmm...?  Not certain this looks quite right.  May need to Sort by something else.

Open to suggestions.

Comment: This is what I am looking for indeed however, if you look at the plot the highest opacity is not the line with the highest y-axis value, why is that?

Comment: Do you want to do this by identifying the curves by the single highest y value?

Comment: @C.E. -- Thanks for adding the plot.

Comment: yes as I mentioned in the question I want the lines to be sorted with respect to y-value from high to low and so their corresponding opacity. The curve with highest value of y should have the highest opacity and the curve with lowest value of y should have the lowest opacity

Comment: @William -- I need to give this some thought.  While I do, you might try Sorting the curves by using something lite `FindMaximum`

Comment: Thanks for the edit but then still the highest curve has the value of y around 1.2 which should the the one with highest opacity. I ran the code and I get the similar wrong result.